# Output an empty alt tag for an image in with views?

Tags: views

I have an image field in a view. How can I output empty alt text for the image.

(For decorative images this is the correct markup 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp )

Comment: Big surprise!  W3CSchools seems to have gotten this one right (at least there is WCAG 2.0 note that says this too: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-GENERAL/H67.html).  However, should never, ever cite W3CSchools as a source for *anything* that has to do with mark-up.  (But see also this note about decorative images: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#a-purely-decorative-image-that-doesn%27t-add-any-information )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have disallowed the "alt" text in your field configuration, the system will output and empty value as you want. But if the field has a value in the attribute, you could modify it with `hook_preprocces_field()`.

Comment: Is the field configuration part of the content type admin screen or a setting for the view's field?

Comment: The field configuration in your content type.